# Missing["reason"]—can any reason be used?

Tags: language-design, missing

Can any string be used as a "reason"? Or is there a specific list of acceptable reasons?

For instance,

```
Missing["refuse"]
```

works as a missing?

Is there any built-in function which takes the "reason" into account? Is there any built-in that behaves differently for different missing reasons?

Comment: In principle any reason can be given. Some standard reasons are: "NotApplicable", "Unknown", "NotAvailable", "Nonexistent", "Indeterminate", "Variable", "Disputed", and "TooLarge". MissingQ will work independently of the reason: MissingQ[Missing["resulteatenbydog"]] => True

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I think the big question is whether the reason ever matters. I am not aware of any such cases, but I never looked very carefully. Since I also use `Missing` in my packages, I would like to be made aware of functions that consider the reason. If you do not want that extra question in your post, feel free to remove it.

Comment: A minor usage: "In TraditionalForm, Missing is typically formatted as \\[LongDash], with a tooltip specifying the reason."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states, `Missing` is "a symbolic object, with no default evaluation rules defined". That means `Missing` is not a function, so it can given any sequence of arguments, none of which have to be a string. However, keep in mind that all its  arguments are evaluated and can have side effects such as affecting the flow of control or incrementing variables. Here is an example:

```
i = 42;
j = Catch[Missing[++i; Throw[bar]]; Abort[]]; 
{i, j}
```

> ```
> {43, bar}
> ```

Now, this is clearly a case where the "reason" matters, ***not*** for its value, but because of the side effects it produces when evaluated.